# CAREL easy refrigerator controller / PTC probe - temperature sensor fluctuation

Tags: temperature, ptc

I have a refrigerator with

- CAREL easy PJEZS6P000 controller
- PTC -50/100C temperature probe.

Been turned off for 6 months. Started it Sunday, worked normal, then Wednesday morning everything was frozen, and -5 deg C. After than the display has shown various temperatures, 0, 4, 9, 12, sometimes -5, while the real measured temperature was about 13 deg C, and setting was 5 C.

Question: what is more common to fail, controller or probe? And what may the above indicate if anything?

Answer (score 1):

It's more situational than you suggest. It's more common for a probe to fail if its been abused (eg. by cleaning) and more common for an instrument to fail if its been abused (eg. by water getting into it). And another possibility is a loose connection, if it's a three-wire probe then variations in either direction are possible from a bad connection.

To troubleshoot you need to do an analysis .. lysis is about breaking apart. So break it apart at the instrument. Measure the probe resistance with an accurate ohmmeter and compare to what it should be (you'll need that information). If it's a Pt RTD the information is easily available. You can replace the sensor with a resistor and see what the controller does.

As a wild guess I would say the probe has failed at the sensor end due to poor construction and thermal cycling, but that's a wild guess at best and only you know what else has transpired, such as cleaning.

Comment: Thx. I'm doing remote assistance on this, so can't test now unfortunately. Just need to decide what to order. It has two 2-wire probes, for ambient and internal temp. Nothing happened to it, but been turned off for 6 months.

Comment: Swapping probes (assuming they're the same) would be an obvious thing to try, assuming the people at the other end are moderately competent.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany maybe that's the problem ... swapped sensors

Comment: @jsotola Remote troubleshooting is such fun. My favorite is the customer who claimed an expensive instrument "just stopped working". Had them send it back and someone had run a forklift tang through the front panel totally destroying it.

Comment: No nothing been changed with this fridge. I actually bought a new controller years ago, because something similar happened. But didn't change it, because the problem lasted only one day, and I wanted the problem to be present so I would know if the replacement helped. Now today it seems to work fine again, so will see if it lasts or not.

Comment: @bretddog maybe something gets covered by ice sometimes